# Check permission Write Attributes on remote files

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, share, file-permissions

I need to check if I can **clear** the **Archive Attribute** on files on a **Windows Share** or **DFS folder**.

I found [How to set, view, change, or remove special permissions for files and folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/en-us), which points to the **Write Attributes** **Special Permission**.

Now I have not found a function in **.Net** to **get information** if the **current process has this permission**. Of course I can try to change the attribute and handle the exception, But I need to know that in advance.

**How would I get or calculate the permission?**

Comment: Quacks like an XY question.  Backups should be performed with a user account that is a member of the "Backup Operators" group.  Automagically gives the program the necessary rights to do these kind of things.  If an admin needs to get involved to correct rights then be sure to log exceptions.  Serverfault.com is the right place to ask questions about this.

Comment: @Hans: My task is to write a very special backup tool that works via Shares or DFS, so I'm stuck with the permissions that I get at that Shares, which I unfortunately cannot changen. The center of the problem is still how to get the information about Write Attributes permissions in .Net, which seems to be not well understood or documented to me.